# XNA 4.0 Frustum Culling

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, xna-4.0, frustum

I need to add frustum-culling rendering technique to my project but I don't know how to do it. Can someone share some code/explanations so I'll have a better idea of how to do it?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/tour and how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to refine your question. As it is it won't get responded. I suggest you to start reading on frustum culling techniques and start developing. Come back whenever you have a concrete question rather than asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got found the solution for my problem by someone explaing about how to use frustum culling with **bounding spheres or boxes**

[Link about how to use bounding spheres and boxes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21779/how-to-draw-only-visible-models-of-the-game)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [BoundingFrustum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/bb195165(v%3Dxnagamestudio.35))  built-in class you can take a look at for a first basic implementation.

Comment: Thank you, but I just found somebody explaining about it in another website.